# Does Hibernate / Spring data JPA support Redis Pipelining?

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, spring-boot, redis

I am using a Spring Boot application with Hibernate and Spring Data JPA with Hibernate L2 as Redis.

During bench marking (50 concurrent users per second running for 30 mins), I could see there are lots of TCP connections originating from the application towards Redis server (through JFR). Since, I am running the bench mark on a normal desktop  (Intel i5 - 4 cores and 8 GB RAM) running on Windows 7 Pro, the machine is not able to open more TCP sockets if I increase the redission configuration beyond 100 netty threads. Redis Connection pooling is set to minimum of 5 and maximum of 100. Even, though the application is processing well, I could see, lots of TCP connections being opened and released for a single request /  response.

I could run the load tests on a server, but I am running the test on a desktop to know about the least thresholds of the application and Redis as well and also to know about the background performance of each of my application's components.

Could anyone please let me know if there is an option of Pipelining in Hibernate / Spring JPA for Redis as I couldn't get much help from the API docs.